# Typescript chainable API for SQL queries

Tags: typescript

Is it possible using Typescript to do something like that:

```
class DSL {

    private sql: string = '';

    get book(): IBook {
        ...
    }

    get author(): IAuthor {
        ...
    }

    get eq(val: string): {
        // Add eq to book/author numbers
    }

    get gt(val: number): {
        // Add gt to book/author numbers
    }

    sql(); // Output the final sql query and return it
}
```

I ultimately wants to write something like:

```
 new DSL().author.name.eq('bob').and.age.gt(20).sql()
```

and have it output:

```
SELECT * FROM AUTHORS WHERE name = 'bob' AND age > 20
```

I'm having trouble applying methods (eq, gt...) per object properties with typing.

Comment: It's an interesting issue you are trying to solve, the problem is that this will be rather limited, at least in the way that you presented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the way you want to write the query, the typings will get a little more compilcated.

Starting from the way you want to write the query, we deduce that `author` should be an object with the same shape as `IAuthor` (ie have all the properties) but each property should be an object that has the appropriate possible operators as methods, accepting the comparator value.

From there we need to return an object with all possible boolean operators and the return type of that gets us back to the original.

Getting this to work for all possible combinations is quite an undertaking, and SO is not the forum for this, but something that works for your sample and should get you started would look something like this:

```
type Fields<T> = {
    [P in keyof T] : Operators<T[P], T>
}

type Operators<TValue, TReturn> = {
    eq(value: TValue):  BoolOperators<TReturn>
    gt(value: TValue):  BoolOperators<TReturn>
}

type BoolOperators<T> = {
    and: Fields<T>,
    or : Fields<T>
    sql(): string;
}

interface IAuthor {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
class DSL {
    get author(): Fields<IAuthor> {
        return null as any // insert reasonable implementation, since the members of the interface are not known at runtime I would suggest a Proxy approach
    }
}

new DSL().author.name.eq('bob').and.age.gt(20).sql() // ok 
new DSL().author.name.eq('bob').and.age.gt("20").sql() // error
```

Hope this helps, feel free to ask follow up questions if you get stuck with specifics, but the above code demonstrates the general approach.